# pandas pivot table change shows values from horizontal to vertical

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Can anybody know there is chance to change in pd.pivot_table show  values.

now I have somthing like that:

```
           exp_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'],'b':['d','d','f'],'n1':[1,1,1],'n2':[5,6,7],'n3':[10,10,10]})
        exp_1
        p1=exp_1.pivot_table(values=['n1','n2','n3'], index='b',columns='a', aggfunc='sum')
        p1re
```

and output is like this:

```
    n1          n2          n3
a   a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
b                                   
d   1.0 1.0 NaN 5.0 6.0 NaN 10.0    10.0    NaN
f   NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 7.0 NaN NaN 10.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvnDN.png)

I want to have values ' names next to the index names instead of columns names like I have it now, how can I do this?

I fount .stack() option and it is almost what i want

now it looks like that

```
s3=pd.DataFrame( p1.stack(0))
s3
```

with output:

```
    a   a   b   c
b               
d   n1  1.0 1.0 NaN
    n2  5.0 6.0 NaN
    n3  10.010.0NaN
f   n1  NaN NaN 1.0
    n2  NaN NaN 7.0
    n3  NaN NaN 10.0
```

but I want to have "n1/2/3" no the first column
is it possible?

Comment: please check my updated answer, if this is not what you want, please provide the exact expected output (type the dataframe manually)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to have "a" and "b" as indexes

From your pivoted table you can stack the last level:

```
p1.stack(-1)
```

output:

```
      n1   n2    n3
b a                
d a  1.0  5.0  10.0
  b  1.0  6.0  10.0
f c  1.0  7.0  10.0
```

But, given the fact that there is nothing to aggregate in the first place (no duplicates), you can simple `set_index` on the initial data:

```
exp_1.set_index(['a', 'b'])
```

output:

```
     n1  n2  n3
a b            
a d   1   5  10
b d   1   6  10
c f   1   7  10
```

#### edit: possible output based on question edit

```
p1.stack(0).droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
a      a     b     c
n1   1.0   1.0   NaN
n2   5.0   6.0   NaN
n3  10.0  10.0   NaN
n1   NaN   NaN   1.0
n2   NaN   NaN   7.0
n3   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

Comment: I want to change positions  of first column to second one not only delete first one

Comment: I am sorry @Adam_Gie but what you want is unclear, please provide the exact expected output in your question (not a description)